# booleans with 3 or more expressions in sh script

Tags: sh, boolean-expression

how can i combine the "OR" and "AND" with 3 or more expressions? I need it for this:

(X or Y or Z) and M

Is this correct?

```
 if [ ["${2}" = "X" -o "${2}" = "Y" -o "${2}" = "Z"] -a "${3}" = "M"]   
     then       
        echo "correct"
        exit 1  
     fi
```

Comment: would `case "${2}" in [XYZ] ) case "${3}" in M ) echo matched correctly ;; * ) echo no match ;; esac ;; * ) echo no base match ;; esac` help? (may not be perfect syntax, but close to the idea). Also standard practice in shell programming is to `exit 0` when a successful outcome .Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shell implemenation isn't required to use `-o` and `-a` as Boolean combinators, and their use is discouraged by the POSIX specification. Instead, use `||` and `&&` to join multiple invocations of `[`.

```
if { [ "$2" = "X" ] || [ "$2" = "Y" ] || [ "$2" = "Z" ]; } && [ "$3" = "M" ]; then
    echo "correct"
    exit 1
fi
```

Note that `[` is a command (an alias for `test`), not a grouping operator, so you can't simply nest them as in your example. In fact, the `]` serves no real purpose; it's just required by `[` to complete the illusion. The above is identical to

```
if { test "$2" = "X" || test "$2" = "Y" || test "$2" = "Z"; } && test "$3" = "M"; then
    echo "correct"
    exit 1
fi
```